# Php machine-learning library?

Tags: php, machine-learning

I am studying on Machine Learning project and I want to do it with php on web. Is it possible and if it is, do you have some suggestion about library or ideas? If it is not , I will continue my project on java with Weka tool.

Comment: You can try this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.svmmodel.php

Comment: Check this one: https://github.com/php-ai/php-ml

Comment: @ArkadiuszKondas this shows page not found

Comment: Try new link: https://gitlab.com/php-ai/php-ml

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one, I haven't tried it though,

https://github.com/gburtini/Learning-Library-for-PHP

I don't think there are many Machine Learning libs built using PHP, in college I built an expert system using Java Jess:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jess_(programming_language)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I will try the gburtini's php library. I hope it works.

Comment: Did gburtini's library work?

Comment: https://libraries.io/search?keywords=machine+learning&languages=PHP  maybe this list contains something useful that can be integrated into a PHP project. I am also currently testing some libraries listed here.